# Variable declaration placement guidelines in VBScript

Tags: variables, vbscript, declaration

Is there any rule for placement of variable declaration in VBScript, like if it should always be declared in the beginning? Or can I declare the variable while using it? Which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with a simple code, with `Option Explicit` included so VBScript parser requests that all the variables used in the code are declared

```vbs
Option Explicit

    WScript.Echo TypeName( data )
    WScript.Echo TypeName( MY_DATA )

Dim data : data = 10
Const MY_DATA = 10

    WScript.Echo TypeName( data )
    WScript.Echo TypeName( MY_DATA )
```

When executed it will ouptut

```
Empty
Integer
Integer
Integer
```

That is

- The first access to `data` does not generate any error. Variable declaration (the `Dim` statement) is hoisted. If the variable is declared inside the same (or outer) scope where it will be used then there will not be any problem.
- But the first output is `Empty`. Only the declaration is hoisted, not the value assignment that is not executed until the line containing it is reached.
- That does not apply to constant declaration. Its value is replaced in code where it is used but the real declaration is delayed until the `const` line is reached (read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/12/07/vbscript-constants-are-not-hoisted/)).

As long as the variables/constants can be reached (they are declared in the same or outer scope) it is irrelevant (to the VBScript parser/engine) where you place the declaration.

But, of course, you or others will have to maintain the code. Being able to put the variables anywhere doesn't mean you should do something like the previous code (please, don't). It is a lot easier to read/maintain the code if variable declaration is done before initialization/usage. The exact way of doing it just depends on coding style.